# API for Apple mail.app? Not Public?

Tags: cocoa, macos, email, osx-snow-leopard

I was looking into Apple Mail.App plugin development and I found nothing in regards to a public api for mail.app, except that there were many websites that said there is no such thing?!

Is that correct? I honestly can't believe it?!

Cheers,
alex25

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. Any and all Mail plugin development is using reverse engineered information.

Comment: Mail.app does have a fairly extensive scriptable interface including provisions for scripts being called from mail rules, so you *might* find that you can do what you want to do via that route.

Answer (score 4):

If you want go into Mail Plug-in "hacking", feel free to join our group: http://groups.google.com/group/apple-mail-dev